# Which .net standard to target in a data model nuget?

Tags: nuget, .net-standard

I am sending data in json format between my applications. One is running in .NET Core, the other one in .NET Framework. Since the same data format can be used by other applications in the future, I wanted to make it usable as easy as possible. So I created it as .NET Standard 1.0 project, added nuspec file and OctoPack to publish a nuget in TeamCity to our local feed.

Now I received a note in code review that I should either target netstandard2.0 instead of netstandard1.0, or at least I should make the nuget with multiple targets. Is this requirement correct? It doesn't make sense to me. Because my nuget does not consume any other libraries, it just provides a simple DTO classes to be used for json files. I think when I do not consume any nugets, then netstandard1.0 is the best target. And I think it makes no sense to make multiple targets (netstandard1.0 and 2.0) since they both would have the same binaries.

Please can someone clarify this? Is there a Microsoft web page which clearly recommends to use lowest possible version of .NET Standard in my case, or is it just my false idea?

Answer (score 0):

When I google ".NET Standard", the first result I get links to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard), which has a table that shows the minimum supported runtimes for each version of .NET Standard, plus a bunch of commentary. That page has a link to an [interactive table](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/dotnet-standard#versions), which some people prefer.

Having said that, in general yes, it's better to just use .NET Standard 2.0. While NuGet and the compiler technically allow .NET 4.6.1 and above to use .NET Standard, they were released before .NET Core/Standard existed and some people run into a bunch of problems because the compatibility isn't really 100%. It's less problematic to use .NET 4.7.2 or above, which I think is the first version of the .NET Framework released after .NET Core and actually works properly in all cases (as far as I know), but it supports .NET Standard 2.0, making all the .NET Standard 1.x versions kind of pointless for .NET Framework compatibility. An assembly with just DTO classes isn't going to encounter any of the compat issues, but some people like to just pretend that .NET Standard started from 2.0 and .NET Framework supports .NET Standard from 4.7.2, because it's easier to remember this one rule than to analyse every situation.

On a side note, I do not recommend using a nuspec to pack SDK style projects (such as .NET Standard or .NET Core), or non-SDK style projects that use `PackageReference`. It's better to use `dotnet pack` or `msbuild -t:pack`. You can specify whatever [NuGet metadata you want in your csproj as MSBuild properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#pack-target).

Comment: I am afraid you focus to a different topic - consuming libraries written in .net standard on various platforms. Then of course you look what is supported by your platform as shown in that table. But I am creating a library, not consuming anything. A plain C# without any platform would be enough in that case (maybe except collections).

Comment: @AlKepp As a package author you need to consider which users you want to support (what TFMs you want your package to be compatible with) and base your decision on that. Hence you need to understand the consumption story in order to know which TFMs your package should support.